# Configuring Lightsail bitnami vsftpd passive

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ftp, vsftpd, bitnami

I've spent a really long time on this and I had it working last night. Came to work this morning and it has stopped working (I am the only IT support and no changes were made by me).

I have configured my firewall on aws as in the below image.

[firewall aws config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lanuW.png)

The server is a bitnami/ubuntu server hosted by aws.

I have configured the vsftpd.conf as below

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#Passive Settings
#listen=yes
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=ftp
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES

#user restriction
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO

# passive/active mode configuration
#port_enable=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1200
pasv_max_port=1250
pasv_address=xx.xx.xx.xx
# if pasv_address_resolve=YES, pasv_address should be a name, e.g. ftp.blah.com
#pasv_addr_resolve=YES


seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

This is what it displays from filezilla:

```
Status:         Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:         Logged in
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/username" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Error:          Could not read from socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:          Disconnected from server
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Output from the cmd prompt:

```
bitnami@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx:~$ sudo ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (localhost:bitnami): username
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-rw-r--    1 1002     1004          415 Feb 08 15:30 1
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,224).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-rw-r--    1 1002     1004          415 Feb 08 15:30 1
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> exit
221 Goodbye.
bitnami@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx:~$
```

I'd really appreciate any help at all as I am very confused.

It works in active mode but a third party can only ftp in passive mode so I need it for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have done all the right things already to prevent most FTP issues by fixing the passive port range and opening that range in your AWS firewall.  The last transcript shows a message: "`227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,224).`" - I would expect to see there the ip-address from your vsftpd.conf setting: `pasv_address=xx.xx.xx.xx` (i.e. your public ip-address)  and not `0.0.0.0` but increase the debug level in filezilla to see the server's PORT response too. -  Second, your problem can be as simple as your work firewall blocking outgoing traffic to TCP port 1200-1250

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `pasv_address` (and `pasv_addr_resolve` options:

> **pasv_address**
>
> Use this option to override the IP address that vsftpd will advertise in response to the PASV command. Provide a numeric IP address, unless pasv_addr_resolve is enabled, in which case you can provide a hostname which will be DNS resolved for you at startup.
>
> Default: (none - the address is taken from the incoming connected socket)
>
> **pasv_addr_resolve**
>
> Set to YES if you want to use a hostname (as opposed to IP address) in the pasv_address option.
>
> Default: NO

(From http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)

I've bugged around with this exact issue last week. Symptoms:

- Using FileZilla in active mode works fine
- Using Automatic or Passive mode results in a timeout or refused connection
- The passive address is printed as `0,0,0,0` in logs

Setting `pasv_address` to an IP, or to an FQDN while setting `passv_addr_resolve` to `yes` solves this problem, as it allows the client to connect to the right destination.